# what is fasttext(AI) and what is it usage?

Tags: machine-learning

Their is any possibility to replace correct word (for eg: instead of effect,affect) in given input file by using fasttext library created by facebook

Answer (score 0):

Not really; the library learns the text, as it is.  There are no facilities for pre-evaluation and editing.  You would have a hard time learning the problem from context: how do you determine that the actual use is, indeed, incorrect?

Comment: thank you, may i know what is fasttext and its process, and why it is used by facebook ? please help me

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on FastText; what still has you confused?  Stack Overflow is not the place for a tutorial.